# Will the boy outwit the teacher in this way?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, puzzle

In the book, Solving Mathematical Problems: A personal perspective (written by Terry Tao), he discusses a problem named (on Analytic Geometry Chapter, page 79):

> Problem 5.4 (Taylor 1989, p. 34, Q2). In the centre of a square swimming
>   pool is a boy, while his teacher (who cannot swim) is at one corner
>   of the pool. The teacher can run three times faster than the boy can swim,
>   but the boy can run faster than the teacher can. Can the boy escape from
>   the teacher? (Assume both persons are infinitely manoeuvrable.)

A picture can be drawn as below, with the boy at O and the teacher at an arbitrary corner, say A. [image]

His solution as is (extremely paraphrased) starting from O, let the boy swim towards BD. Let the boy stop (at say X) when the teacher is at Y (A < Y < B) and AY = 3OX. Now tricking the teacher, make a straight dash towards CD.

I am having a much different solution (restricting the boys movement to a straight line).

> Putting the square in Cartesian plane with O as the origin and and the teacher at D **(Not A)**. Assuming the square is of lenght $2k$, the teachers coordinate is $( k, -k)$. Now, lets suppose the boy makes a dash to a point on AB (say P $(x, k)$ ) and reaches faster than the teacher. So to go to P, the teacher has to move in D->B->P, with a total distance of $3k-x$. The boy should go $\sqrt{x^2 + k^2}$. Now from the ratio of the speed of the two, it reduces to solving the inequality $\sqrt{x^2 + k^2} < \frac{3k -x}{3} = k - \frac{x}{3}$, which solves to $\frac{-3k}{4} < x < 0$.

So a straight dash to a bit left of the midpoint of AB is also probably a correct answer, isn't it ? [My main point of asking is not to check the answer numerically, which can be done by a sleeping baby with its left hand, but the method's correctenss]

Comment: bonus: For any regular polygon $n$, find the maximum ratio of velocities that allow the boy to escape. for $n = \infty$ (a circle), it is $\pi$

Comment: actually, if you know the answer to the bonus question please write it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1762665/can-the-boy-escape-the-teacher-for-a-regular-n-gon